# Jxl and maximum number of formatted cells

Tags: jxl

When I'm writing Excel files with jxl and use your own cell format, I get this warning: The maximum number of formatted cells has exprired. Using default format". I have about 350 cells that need to be formatted, which seems relatively little to me. Am I doing something wrong?  I use loops to set my cell format. Or is there any way to increase the number of formatted cells? My whole code this long, but here is a simple example of doing formatting:

for (int=0;i<30;i++) }
  ws.getWritableCell(2, i).setCellFormat(sumrow());
{

Comment: Found the answer myself. You can't use much setCellformat method, so you have to put the formatters in the method where you add the cell's content (number,label, formula and so on),

Answer (score 8):

How are you creating the `CellFormat` objects?

What you want to do is to make sure you are reusing the `CellFormat` objects and not recreating them in a loop somewhere.

That is unless you really have 350 cells that each have a *different* formatting. Otherwise create a single `CellFormat` object and pass that into `setCellFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the NumberFormat to EXPONENTIAL. It worked for me. Like this:-
NumberFormats.EXPONENTIAL